# How to solve $|1+x|\frac{|\alpha-\beta|}{|\alpha + \beta|} + \max\{1, |x|\} \leq 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, roots

I am trying to solve $$|1+x|\frac{|\alpha-\beta|}{|\alpha + \beta|} + \max\{1, |x|\} \leq 1 \tag{1}, $$ with $\alpha<\beta<0$. Using

$$\max(x, y) = \frac{x + y + |x - y|}{2}$$

in $(1)$ we get
$$p(x) = -2(\alpha-\beta ) |1+x| + (1+\alpha+\beta)|x| - (\alpha + \beta)|1-x| \leq 0.$$ Can you please provide some guidelines to proceed? Is there an alternative way?

Comment: Conisder the cases a) $|x| \leq 1$, b) $x>1$ and c) $x<-1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy what is the intuition to select these intervals? Also can we split it including zero in the intervals?

Comment: Can we handle it with change of variable?

Comment: To get rid of maximum  consider the cases $|x|\leq 1$ and $|x|>1$. To get rid of absolute value consider the cases $1+x \geq 0$ an 1+x <0$. Very simple and intuitive !

Answer (score 1):

one can solve this by splitting the interval into 4 parts

$$assuming\qquad\frac{|\alpha-\beta|}{|\alpha + \beta|}=a$$ 
since it is given that$\,\alpha<\beta<0$,
one can say 0<a<1 
case(1): $x\le-1$  
$$-a(x+1)-x \le 1$$
$$\Rightarrow x(a+1)\ge -(a+1)$$
$$\Rightarrow x\ge-1$$
$\therefore $  x = -1 is only solution in this case 
case(2): $-1{\lt}\,x\le0$ 
$$a(1+x)+1\le1$$
$$\Rightarrow x\le-1$$
$\therefore$ no solution in this case 
case(3): $0{\lt}\,x\lt1$ 
$$a(1+x)+1\le1$$
$$\Rightarrow x\le-1$$
$\therefore $ no solution in this case 
case(4): $x\ge1$ 
$$a(x+1)+x\le1$$
$$\Rightarrow x\le{\frac{1-a}{1+a}}\lt1$$
$\therefore $ no solution in this case 
$$\therefore x=-1 \;is \;the \;only \;solution.$$

Comment: Edits are encouraged if one can make my solution more clear by typesetting etc